# JSON processing in Python without json or simplejson

Tags: python, json

I have a somewhat unique and frustrating situation. I need to do some JSON processing in Python, but with the following limitations:

- I'm stuck with Python 2.4.3 (so no `json` module).
- I can't install anything we don't currently have (so no old versions of `simplejson`).

My employer is a very large company, and I don't think I would have the ability to change either of the above issues with any speed. Do I have any options here besides doing all of my JSON processing manually, or switching to another language entirely?

Comment: `simplejson` can be used just like any other module, bundled with your project. Are you sure you cannot use it? You don't even have to compile the C extension (offering speedups).

Comment: The script I'm writing is going to be used on multiple machines, which may not have access to all of the same programs and Python modules (otherwise I could be using Python 2.6). I can see about adding it to our paths, but there isn't much guarantee it will work since I don't know if I can add it to all the necessary systems.

Comment: I mean you *bundle it with your script*.

Comment: Oh, you mean in a way besides just using `import`? I didn't actually know that was an option. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Any module you put next to your script can be imported. The directory of your script is always added to the path, so if you put `simplejson` right next to the script it can be imported.

Comment: I didn't know that about the directory. That's something that can probably be done, so I will look into that as my first option. Now to track down an older version of `simplejson`. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: The current release of `simplejson` supports Python 2.5 and newer.

Comment: All previous releases are available on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/simple/simplejson/

Comment: Excellent, thanks! If you want to submit an official answer I can offer you the rep points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory your script is run from is always added to the `sys.path` module search path, so you can just bundle `simplejson` with your script.

The current [`simplejson` release](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) can be used on Python 2.5 and up, but you can always find older releases in the [PyPI simple index for the project](https://pypi.python.org/simple/simplejson/).

Note that the project uses a C extension for speedups; not compiling it is fine but JSON loading and dumping will be slower.